# What's the equivalent of pmdGet3DCoordinates for Intel RealSense 3D camera (SR300)?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, realsense

I am trying to write the similar code for a PMD camera now for an Intel RealSense 3D camera (SR300). However, I can't find a method that does the same thing in the realsense SDK. Is there a hack for this or what do you suggest?

```
pmdGet3DCoordinates(PMDHandle hnd, float * data, size_t size);
```

an example usage is:

```
float * cartesianDist = new float[nRows*nCols*3];
res = pmdGet3DCoordinates(hnd, cartesianDist, nCols*nRows*3*sizeOf(float));
```

I need this function in order to create an xyzmap as in the code below:

```
int res = pmdGet3DCoordinates(hnd, dists, 3 * numPixels * sizeof(float)); 
xyzMap = cv::Mat(xyzMap.size(), xyzMap.type(), dists);
```

I have written the following code so far, I don't know if it make any sense in terms of Intel RealSense. Please feel free to comment.

```
void SR300Camera::fillInZCoords()
{
    //int res = pmdGet3DCoordinates(hnd, dists, 3 * numPixels * sizeof(float)); //store x,y,z coordinates dists (type: float*)
    ////float * zCoords = new float[1]; //store z-Coordinates of dists in zCoords
    //xyzMap = cv::Mat(xyzMap.size(), xyzMap.type(), dists);
    Projection *projection = pp->QueryCaptureManager()->QueryDevice()->CreateProjection();
    std::vector<Point3DF32> vertices;
    vertices.resize(bufferSize.width * bufferSize.height);
    projection->QueryVertices(sample->depth, &vertices[0]);
    xyzBuffer.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize.width*bufferSize.height; i++) {
        //cv::Point3f p;
        //p.x = vertices[i].x;
        //p.y = vertices[i].y;
        //p.z = vertices[i].z;
        //xyzBuffer.push_back(p);
        xyzBuffer.push_back(cv::Point3f(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z));
    }



    xyzMap = cv::Mat(xyzBuffer);
    projection->Release();
}
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for [mat.reshape()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#abca74fa43163dba52b70af4b48c69f62)

Comment: @RickM. please check the update

Comment: From what you've added, I still can't say what you want. I'd still write the first comment again, but it's just a guess. How do you want this `xyzmap`? Matrix wise

Comment: same  format as xyzMap (cv::Mat) https://communities.intel.com/message/474715#474715

Answer (score 1):

`sts = projection->QueryVertices(depthMap, &pos3D[0]);` is an almost equivalent and does the job of converting depth UV-map to real-world xyz map.

```
   Status sts = sm ->AcquireFrame(true);


        if (sts < STATUS_NO_ERROR) {
            if (sts == Status::STATUS_STREAM_CONFIG_CHANGED) {
                wprintf_s(L"Stream configuration was changed, re-initilizing\n");
                sm ->Close();
            }
        }

        sample = sm->QuerySample();
        PXCImage *depthMap = sample->depth;
        renderd.RenderFrame(sample->depth);
        PXCImage::ImageData depthImage;
        depthMap->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ, &depthImage);
        PXCImage::ImageInfo imgInfo = depthMap->QueryInfo();
        int depth_stride = depthImage.pitches[0] / sizeof(pxcU16);
        PXCProjection * projection = device->CreateProjection();
        pxcU16 *dpixels = (pxcU16*)depthImage.planes[0];
        unsigned int dpitch = depthImage.pitches[0] / sizeof(pxcU16);
        PXCPoint3DF32 *pos3D = new PXCPoint3DF32[num_pixels];
        sts = projection->QueryVertices(depthMap, &pos3D[0]);
        if (sts < Status::STATUS_NO_ERROR) {
            wprintf_s(L"Projection was unsuccessful! \n");
            sm->Close();
        }
```